# Footnote formatting in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, footnote

I have a document with footnotes that sit above the page footer. When I insert a footnote, I get this extra formatting, (the 1._________ bit) above the footnotes.

I want to remove it, but I can't even select it. It disappears when I remove the footnote and reappears when I add in another footnote. It doesn't seem to be related to the footer as I can remove the footer and it remains.

Any ideas what it is and how to get rid of it?

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the View tab
2. Click Draft in the Document views group
3. Go to the References tab
4. Click Show notes in the Footnotes group
5. In the Footnotes pane combobox select Footnote separator
6. Delete the line